# Bootcamp cannot find both systems at startup

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, dual-boot

Something strange happened:

1. I closed my macbook pro while using windows 10
2. When I opened it again it didn't wake up for a while so I forced it to shut down by pressing the power button for 10 seconds
3. When I restarted the computer, it could not find any OS and just displayed a [flashing question mark](http://trcdatarecovery.com/articles/mac-flashing-question-mark). I tried starting the computer while pressing the usual [special keys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255), but nothing worked.
4. I gave up and went for 2 days of vacations, instead of being angry.
5. I just came back from vacations (after two days) and everything works fine.

**Update**

Today nothing works, it is impossible to find the SSD, even when I try OS X Recovery over the Internet Disk  Utility does not find the SSD (just a drive of about 1.28 Go where the OS X recovery is installed). I tried reseting the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) without any luck.

Is it necessarily a [disk failure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139542/macbook-air-intermittently-cant-find-startup-disk)?

**Update 2**

It's not a disk failure since I installed my SSD into a friend's Macbook Pro (same model: retina 15" late 2013, 2.3Ghz) and it works properly. I also tried to insert his SSD into my Macbook Pro and it is not recognized.

I returned my computer to an Apple reseller...

Comment: Did you try to boot into Recovery or Single User mode?

Comment: Yes it didn't help. I think my question is clear enough now.

Comment: Diagnosing potential hardware issues is always difficult without physical access to the machine, so it helps to be very specific. In step 3, what actually was displayed, a flashing question mark as shown in the picture behind the link? Which "special keys" did you try? Also, what does "nothing works" mean now? Same problem as in step 3?

Comment: The only way to find out whether this is a disk failure is to run the tests recommended in the answers to the question you've already linked to.

Comment: Yes it is the question mark flashing, of course. I obviously tried all [appropriate special keys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). Now the disk is not recognized at all anymore so I can't run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

*Author of the question answering:*

It's not necessarily a disk failure since I installed my SSD into a friend's Macbook Pro (same model: retina 15" late 2013, 2.3Ghz) and it works properly. I also tried to insert his SSD into my Macbook Pro and it is not recognized.

I don't know where it comes from though...