# Figuring out bad sectors in my Macintosh HD

Tags: hard-drive

As the title suggests, what's the best way to go about doing this?

I'm talking about figuring out bad sectors in the hard drive that already has OS X installed, and that I'm using right now to do stuff.

Of course the correct answer would be some software that runs from a USB, and that's compatible with Mac, or something like that. Could somebody point me to this?

Comment: Similar: [Checking for bad blocks without formatting](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73423/8546) (2012-12-01)