# How can I avoid repeated "Time Machine must create a new backup" errors when backing up to a third party NAS?

Tags: macos, time-machine

My backups seem to go well backing up to my NAS however randomly after a few weeks I get the following error.  Several users get this error intermittently however I have yet to find a solution. Any ideas?

> Time Machine completed a verification of your backups on “NAS”. To
>   improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you.
>
> Click Start New Backup to create a new backup. This will remove your
>   existing backup history. This could take several hours.
>
> Click Back Up Later to be reminded tomorrow. Time Machine won’t
>   perform backups during this time.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Suitability of HFS Plus

Whilst Time Machine must use HFS Plus for most things, it's worth noting that **the file system is not ideally suited for the task**.

### An example

Coincidence: a few hours after my first edition of this answer, my own *Time Machine Backups* volume (a sparse bundle disk image) suffered a file system failure. I'm certain that the underlying storage is OK – a ZFS pool scrubbed, without error, before and after the HFS Plus failure. For the record:

```
2013-06-07 18:02:54.332 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Starting automatic backup
2013-06-07 18:02:56.292 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Resizing backup disk image from 2.65 TB to 2.6 TB
2013-06-07 18:03:34.119 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Disk image /Volumes/tall/com.apple.backupd/GPES3E-gjp4-1.sparsebundle mounted at: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups
2013-06-07 18:03:35.244 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
2013-06-07 18:03:44.013 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Inherited root volume OS, UUID: C5C41F95-133B-3EB0-9013-F94DAAA0D99B
2013-06-07 18:03:44.147 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Forcing deep traversal on source: "OS" (mount: '/' fsUUID: 03AF4C8A-66E8-3DE2-B30F-176C0C2337C3 eventDBUUID: BDCB9532-A4A8-4B94-A6C1-928FD741B07A)
2013-06-07 18:03:44.148 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Event store UUIDs don't match for volume: spare
2013-06-07 18:03:44.150 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Event store UUIDs don't match for volume: disk0s3
2013-06-07 18:03:47.612 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-103948 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.663 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215311 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.714 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-075155 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.764 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-055748 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.827 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-220121 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.888 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-081211 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:47.966 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215312 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.025 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-235752 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.087 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-140311 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.145 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215718 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.202 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-005749 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.261 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-235753 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.321 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-160310 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.558 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-074020 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.619 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-025748 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.709 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-015751 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.904 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-025749 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:48.954 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-015752 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.004 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-130310 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.055 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-045748 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.162 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215950 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.211 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-092036 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.273 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-035751 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.321 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-225752 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.371 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-065747 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.420 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-045749 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.470 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-213710 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.519 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-091305 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.589 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-150310 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.639 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-065748 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.688 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-074521 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.776 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-220105 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.838 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-225749 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:49.899 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-092118 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:50.119 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-120311 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:50.388 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Mobile backup /Volumes/MobileBackups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-07-035749 does not contain spare.  Skipping it.
2013-06-07 18:03:51.141 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Deep event scan at path:/ reason:must scan subdirs|require scan|
2013-06-07 18:03:51.141 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Finished scan
2013-06-07 18:16:29.077 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Deep event scan at path:/Volumes/spare reason:must scan subdirs|new event db|
2013-06-07 18:16:29.086 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Finished scan
2013-06-07 18:16:29.570 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Deep event scan at path:/Volumes/disk0s3 reason:must scan subdirs|new event db|
2013-06-07 18:16:29.786 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Finished scan
2013-06-07 18:16:30.310 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Found 1695685 files (84.93 GB) needing backup
2013-06-07 18:16:31.053 com.apple.backupd[18433]    109.44 GB required (including padding), 2 TB available
2013-06-07 18:54:10.918 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Unexpected result from MDBackupIndexFile (1) for: /Applications/Freenet/datastore/CHK-cache.hd, /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215332.inProgress/9086512E-E386-475E-AE99-34BAA1D2E485/OS/Applications/Freenet/datastore/CHK-cache.hd
2013-06-07 18:54:24.848 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Unexpected result from MDBackupIndexFile (1) for: /Applications/Freenet/datastore/CHK-store.hd, /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215332.inProgress/9086512E-E386-475E-AE99-34BAA1D2E485/OS/Applications/Freenet/datastore/CHK-store.hd
2013-06-07 19:03:44.609 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 18.81 GB of 84.93 GB, 460244 of 1695685 items
2013-06-07 20:03:44.827 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 34.12 GB of 84.93 GB, 815234 of 1695685 items
2013-06-07 21:03:54.004 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 40.73 GB of 84.93 GB, 1013214 of 1695685 items
2013-06-07 22:03:54.678 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 67.55 GB of 84.93 GB, 1508426 of 1695685 items
2013-06-07 22:28:43.226 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 1786731 files (77.59 GB) from volume OS.
2013-06-07 22:28:49.157 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Unexpected result from MDBackupIndexFile (1) for: /Volumes/spare/Tocar y Luchar JAA.cdr, /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/GPES3E-gjp4-1/2013-06-06-215332.inProgress/9086512E-E386-475E-AE99-34BAA1D2E485/spare/Tocar y Luchar JAA.cdr
2013-06-07 22:28:51.508 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Error: Flushing index to disk returned an error: 1
2013-06-07 22:28:51.508 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Copied 1786746 files (77.59 GB) from volume spare.
2013-06-07 22:29:11.108 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Backup canceled.
2013-06-07 22:29:23.227 com.apple.backupd[18433]    Ejected Time Machine disk image: /Volumes/tall/com.apple.backupd/GPES3E-gjp4-1.sparsebundle
2013-06-07 23:10:44.791 com.apple.backupd[28884]    Starting automatic backup
2013-06-07 23:10:45.269 com.apple.backupd[28884]    Backup failed with error: 1002
2013-06-07 23:10:45.382 com.apple.backupd[28884]    Starting automatic backup
2013-06-07 23:10:46.446 com.apple.backupd[28884]    Resizing backup disk image from 2.6 TB to 2.6 TB
2013-06-07 23:10:50.162 com.apple.backupd[28884]    Runtime corruption detected on /Volumes/tall/com.apple.backupd/GPES3E-gjp4-1.sparsebundle (fsck_hfs -q termination status: 3)
```

- the message at 2013-06-07 22:28:49 is eye-catching, but **expected** in my case (symptom of a bug involving HFS Plus; a corruption that involves AppleFSCompression) – probably negligible in the context of this answer
- the message at 2013-06-07 22:28:51 may be more relevant to the file system failure.

`/private/var/log/fsck_hfs.log` then showed:

```
/dev/rdisk7s2: fsck_hfs run at Fri Jun  7 23:10:48 2013
/dev/rdisk7s2: ** /dev/rdisk7s2 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk7s2:    Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557.3.1~5).
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM DIRTY

/dev/rdisk7s2: fsck_hfs run at Fri Jun  7 23:10:49 2013
/dev/rdisk7s2: ** /dev/rdisk7s2 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk7s2:    Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557.3.1~5).
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM DIRTY
```

Confirming that no error affected the underlying storage at the time:

```
GPES3E-gjp4-1:~ gjp22$ date
Sat  8 Jun 2013 06:57:46 BST
GPES3E-gjp4-1:~ gjp22$ uptime
 6:57  up 21:51, 5 users, load averages: 0.92 1.27 1.37
GPES3E-gjp4-1:~ gjp22$ zpool status
  pool: gjp22
 state: ONLINE
 scan: scrub repaired 0 in 24h8m with 0 errors on Sat May 25 23:25:38 2013
config:

    NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    gjp22                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
      GPTE_71B8BDA2-3EBA-4B91-9E1C-2AE2B1DAAD06  ONLINE       0     0     0  at disk3s2
    cache
      GPTE_2605CCB0-67B7-4C93-A4B1-83EF764CE617  OFFLINE        1.48Ki     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: tall
 state: ONLINE
 scan: scrub repaired 0 in 28h10m with 0 errors on Sun May 26 18:47:22 2013
config:

    NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tall                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      GPTE_78301A52-4AFF-4D96-8DE9-E76ABC14909C  ONLINE       0     0     0  at disk2s2
      GPTE_99056308-F5E2-4314-852C-4DA04732A2D0  ONLINE       0     0     0  at disk6s2

errors: No known data errors
GPES3E-gjp4-1:~ gjp22$
```

## In simple terms

Whilst we'd like a solution, file system failures such as this seem to be:

- unpredictable
- unavoidable
- sometimes irreparable.

In the absence of a good solution, my best advice is to not rely on a single Time Machine backup. The risk of eventual failure and inability to repair is simply too high.

### Degrees of failure

In the past I sometimes forced [`fsck_hfs`(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck_hfs.8.html) to rebuild b-tree files … with limited success but not certainty. Whilst a file system may *appear* to be OK (in Disk Utility and the like) I would not no longer trust it for Time Machine backup or restoration purposes.

In the most recent case (above) multiple applications of force (multiple rebuilds of the catalog b-tree, a rebuild of the extended attributes b-tree and a rebuild of the extents b-tree) have not led to a verifiable file system. I have debug logs from these attempts, which I'll not begin to summarise here; they're massive.

With locally attached disks (USB 2.0), attempts to repair Time Machine backup volumes can be *extraordinarily* time consuming. Wireless – over AFP – you may find the time required *intolerable*.

---

[Time Machine - Troubleshooting – C13.  "…Time Machine must create a new backup for you."](http://pondini.org/TM/C13.html) (James Pond) includes much useful information. Essentially:

> … backups are corrupted beyond Disk Utility's ability to fix …

When OS X reports that an HFS Plus *file system* appears to be OK, there may be significant issues with the *disk* – issues that OS X simply can not detect.

As corruption has occurred more than once, there may be a problem with:

- hardware, firmware and/or software of the NAS.

What make and model is the NAS?

## Hard disks of the NAS

If the OS of the NAS allows you to verify **integrity of blocks on its disks**: please do so.

If the OS of the NAS lacks that capability, then aim to boot the hardware with a different OS that's more suitable for testing. [Options might include Ubuntu and a run of badblocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88904/8546).

Checks of this type:

- will be time consuming; but
- should help you to determine whether the state of the disk(s) is contributory to the multiple failures.

Answer (score 7):

To add to @GrahamPerrin ’s warning, I want to share my plan for that.

[My NAS](http://www.dlugosz.com/zeta/?p=186) is running [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) which features [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS_data_integrity).

Aware of the “Time Machine must create a new backup” issue before setting things up, I made the TimeMachine host volume on the NAS a separate ZFS Volume, used only for that.  Then I specified daily volume [snapshots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Snapshots_and_clones).  If the contents of the `ZPool1/Backups/TimeMachine` volume get corrupted due to network snafu or the general unreliability of HFS+ virtual disk inside another volume, I can roll it back on the NAS.  I sometimes call this the *meta backup*.

To be clear,

- the Host Volume is the NAS storage `ZPool1/Backups/TimeMachine`
- it contains a HFS+ virtual disk, as host's directory `"John's MacBook Pro.sparsebundle"` which itself has a `bands` subdirectory containing the fully-provisioned virtual drive storage as 951 files with names like `e8` (hex numbers counting up from 0).
- The virtual disk is how Time Machine automatically handles a target volume that’s not HFS+.  But I [created it ahead of time to make chunk sizes efficient](http://endlessgeek.com/2014/03/improve-time-machine-performance-big-bands/) (128M each file).
- the NAS publishes `ZPool1/Backups/TimeMachine` as an AFP share with the “use for Time Machine” flag set.  TimeMachine expects that to contain the virtual disk which it then uses, or creates if it’s the first use of that network location for backing up.

So, the ZFS volume snapshot capability works because it’s a ZFS volume containing a bunch of 128MB data files with boring names.  Time Machine works because it puts a virtual disk formatted as HFS+ on whatever file system was presented.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I first configured Time Machine to use my NAS - every few weeks, I'd get the popup at the top of this thread.  It was very frustrating.  I noticed over time, however, that this only happened on particular days of the week.  And I then realized that it only happened during the weekly scrub (Monday morning) or resync (Tuesday morning) operations.  So I obtained a copy of "Time Machine Editor" which lets you tell Time Machine when it can and can't run, excluded Monday and Tuesday mornings, and voila, problem solved.

Comment: I got the problem on Friday.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto Ronald Pottol's suggestion, the following converts a sparsebundle rather than re-creating it. Once this is done, just rename the bundles.

```
hdiutil convert MyMac_001acb9cb23d.sparsebundle -format UDSB -tgtimagekey sparse-band-size=2097152 -o NEW_MyMac_001acb9cb23d.sparsebundle
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are hitting the max file count for the destination directory? In a classic Unix file system like ext2, you have a limit of 32,000 (2^15) files (or sub-directories or links (things)) per directory. A Time Machine backup is a sparse disk image, which is a bunch of 8MB files. 300GB of 8MB files is something like 37,000. Ooops.

You can increase the size of the files that Time Machine uses in the sparse bundle (these instructions would increase the max size of your backup by 16), or change the file system on the NAS, Reiserfs, ext4 (some versions of ext3), etc, probably will work, if this is the issue.

User KingKongFrog added this answer, I'm adding it to my answer (but upvote his as well), this lets you convert your existing backup to the larger size

```
hdiutil convert MyMac_001acb9cb23d.sparsebundle -format UDSB -tgtimagekey sparse-band-size=2097152 -o NEW_MyMac_001acb9cb23d.sparsebundle
```

[link to the blog I got this from](http://sansumbrella.com/writing/2012/the-reluctant-sysadmin-nas-time-machine/)

```
# creates a sparsebundle disk image with a 128MB band size
MACHINE_NAME=your-machine-name
echo $MACHINE_NAME
hdiutil create -size 900g -type SPARSEBUNDLE -nospotlight -volname "Backup of $MACHINE_NAME" -fs "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+" -imagekey sparse-band-size=262144 -verbose ./$MACHINE_NAME.sparsebundle

# copy the plists from TIME_MACHINE_IMAGE to NEW_IMAGE
TIME_MACHINE_IMAGE=your-machine-name.old.sparsebundle
NEW_IMAGE=your-machine-name.sparsebundle
cp $TIME_MACHINE_IMAGE/com.apple.TimeMachine.*.plist $NEW_IMAGE
```

Comment: [HFS Plus supports up to 2.1 billion files (or files and folders) in a folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2422).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that tries to fix Time Machine backup bundle following instructions from [here](https://jd-powered.net/notes/fixing-your-time-machine-backup/). It also available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mxl/22dc8d5766f5f3c3c7ecdd011c86d107).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BACKUP_PATH=$1

if [ -z "$BACKUP_PATH" ]; then
    echo "Please provide path to Time Machine backup bundle."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Don't forget to enable Full Disk Access in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Full Disk Access -> check Terminal or iTerm item"
chflags -R nouchg "$BACKUP_PATH"
VOLUME_ID=$(hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck "$BACKUP_PATH" | grep "Apple_HFS" | awk '{print $1}')
fsck_hfs -drfy "$VOLUME_ID"
hdiutil detach "$VOLUME_ID"
sed -i '' -e '/<key>VerificationState<\/key>/ {' -e 'n; s/<integer>.*<\/integer>/<integer>0<\/integer>/' -e '}' "$BACKUP_PATH/com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist"
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to address an additional factor in the so-called "corruption".

I had something similar: macOS backing up to an SMB share on my (virtualised) NAS, hosted on ZFS. Actually I'm using an ext4 volume for holding the sparsebundle, since decent Linux support for HFS/APFS isn't really all that existent. This way I can at least properly access the raw data directly from my NAS while still feeding macOS an HFS sparsebundle. I'm not encrypting the backup for the exact reason of being able to recover it outside macOS. This had been running fine for quite some time, but today it suddenly decided things were "corrupted". Trying to mount it outside of Time Machine didn't work to begin with:

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck mymac.sparsebundle
hdiutil: attach failed - image not recognized
```

But ZFS was just scrubbed recently and reported zero issues, also I can edit files through my NAS without any problems (I used the XML files for testing). This makes it sound more like an access problem than actual corruption. I only ever use one and the same SMB user for accessing the share and I'm not even backing up multiple Macs, so ownership issues should be ruled out. I decided to check the **owner** permissions instead:

```
$ find mymac.sparsebundle ! -perm -u+r -o ! -perm -u+w -o ! -perm -u+x
mymac.sparsebundle
mymac.sparsebundle/bands/1ac69
# snipped, there are 31432 hits for files in /bands/
mymac.sparsebundle/com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.bckup
mymac.sparsebundle/token
```

Notice how even **the sparsebundle itself** is missing at least one of the permissions. It seems that all hits returned by `find` are missing `+x`, which is quite problematic since I now cannot "execute" the sparsebundle (**read its contents**). Just to be sure I checked for files in `/bands/` that **do** have `rwx` permissions for the owner:

```
$ find mymac.sparsebundle/bands -type f -perm -u+rwx | wc -l
77868
```

So it seems like everything really should have `u+rwx` set, even regular files. This may be due to the sparsebundle format, the ext4 volume or even something due to SMB. Anyways, let's correct that: `chmod -Rv u+rwx mymac.sparsebundle`.

However, that wasn't enough as Time Machine still complained. Apparently it stores some "panic" information in the sparsebundle's XML files and you can find fixes for it all over the place (including other answers to this very question), but I got mine in particular from [here](https://gist.github.com/ahknight/dec202583a910756c6d9). I slightly adjusted to my taste:

```
$ cd mymac.sparsebundle
$ chflags -R -v nouchg . # The gist doesn't use -R but uses only specific paths
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :RecoveryBackupDeclinedDate" com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :VerificationState 0" com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist
$ hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck .
/dev/disk4              GUID_partition_scheme
/dev/disk4s1            EFI
/dev/disk4s2            Apple_HFS
$ fsck_hfs -fy -c 8gb /dev/rdisk4s2 # I made a habit of using rdisk* instead of disk* for low-level operations like this
# snipped some output, but it ended with:
** The volume Time Machine Backups appears to be OK.
$ hdiutil detach /dev/disk4
"disk4" ejected.
```

I can finally resume my backups without having lost the entire history. I'm not really sure what caused the permissions issue, perhaps due to a network hiccup the commands sent by Time Machine didn't quite make it through. Or some problem with ACL inheritance.

Note that the `fsck_hfs` seems to be necessary, even after modifying the `plist` properties and fixing permissions. I think it still flips some bits that tell macOS the volume is now actually healthy (again).

---

Update 2022-06-14: the exact same permissions problem happened again when I entered Time Machine and interrupted it while it was loading. This time it could still partially mount the sparsebundle but I was still getting `Permission denied` everywhere. So I simply corrected it again and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to share my experience about this and to invite you giving feedback.

I had the corrupted backups error, so I tried without success the solution given by Ronald Pottol. I always reached an `hdiutil: create failed - ...` error when creating the Sparsbundle on my NAS (a home made NAS running Debian Wheezy and an ext4 partition).

So, after some googling, I tried this (from [there](http://appleclinic.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/time-machine-on-nas/)):

1. Get the identifier of the computer:

   `$ ifconfig en0 | grep ether | sed s/://g | sed s/ether//`

   `b88d120afd6c`
2. Use that identifier to create a sparsebundle (in your home dir) with the parameters from Ronald Pottol (ComputerName is to be replaced with the actual computer name)

   `sudo hdiutil create -size 190g -type SPARSEBUNDLE -nospotlight -volname "Backup of ComputerName" -fs "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+" -imagekey sparse-band-size=262144 -verbose ~/ComputerName_b88d120afd6c`

   "Backup of ComputerName" should be replaced with a string that matches your language settings. In french: "Copies de sauvegarde Time Machine"

   Add `-encryption AES-128 -stdinpass` (e.g. after `-verbose`) to enable encryption for the backup. You will be prompted for an encryption password. You may also use `AES-256` instead of `AES-128`.
3. Mount the NAS drive that will contain the Time Machine backups.
4. Using the Finder, copy the created Sparsbundle from Home directory to that drive.
5. Configure Time Machine to use the NAS drive. If encryption was enabled choose to use the same backup files and confirm the password you set earlier.
6. Run a first backup.

In the Console utility, a message should be written, indicating the sparsebundle was renamed. So it has the correct sparse-band-size parameter that should avoid future errors:

```
18/07/2014 06:50:25,712 com.apple.backupd[3573]: Renaming /Volumes/tmNasDrive-1/ComputerName_b88d120afd5c.sparsebundle to /Volumes/tmNasDrive-1/ComputerName.sparsebundle
```

I did not have any errors since I started this new backup, but this does not mean this solution is really reliable. I hope this will help. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: I'm curious if that has supposably permanently resolved the issue. As some years have passed could you comment on whether you ever experienced that error again?

Comment: Unfortunately, my NAS backup got corrupted few months ago and I did not try to restore it or create a new one. If I do, I'll try to give you a word about it

Answer (score 0):

The most concise instruction (it worked and recovered my TM backup sparsebundles) I found at

http://jd-powered.net/notes/fixing-your-time-machine-backup

and

http://tonylawrence.com/post/unix/fixing-corrupted-time-machine-backups/
which seems to be the original article (2012)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  It's better to put the details here and link to them as supporting sources rather than just provide link(s) with commentary.  Links often go stale making the answer useless.